# Accessing to the NextJs Link href property from children component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm working on an *active button* behaviour using NextJs.

Right now every button is contained in a **Next** `link` component as follows:

```
<Link href={href} key={key} passHref>
  <MenuItem
    disableRipple
    style={{ color: router.pathname === href && "#5e62ff" }}
  >
    {localizedTitle(label)}
  </MenuItem>
</Link>
```

[image]

As you can see, `link` is passing the `href` to the children components, and it can be ensured by looking in the **React** tools section, but the  `href` property on the `MenuItem` component is not defined.

How can i get the `link` `href` component from its children(`MenuItem` in this case)?

Comment: Doesn't this href may come from the ListContext.Provider? isnt it possible to directly pass the href to the MenuItem component?

Comment: No, it comes from the *NextJs* `link` component itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for using the `className` attribute instead of using an `style`, plus in the new version it seems this bug was fixed.

```
import {
  MenuItem,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import Link from "next/link";
---
{navLinks &&
                  Object.keys(navLinks).length !== 0 &&
                  menuLinks.map(({ key, href, label }) => (
                    <Link href={href} key={key} passHref>
                      <MenuItem
                        role="tab"
                        disableRipple
                        className={
                          router.pathname === href ? classes.activeItem : ""
                        }
                        onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
                      >
                        {localizedTitle(label)}
                      </MenuItem>
                    </Link>
                  ))}
```